# How to resolve the error The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ss:authentication-manager'?

Tags: mule, basic-authentication, ram

I'm trying to implement Basic authentication in ramal, based on below link.

```
https://dzone.com/articles/mulesoft-basic-authentication-with-https
```

Anypoint XML, i have added

```
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security" xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

  <spring:beans>
   <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
     <ss:authentication-provider>
       <ss:user-service id="userService">
          <ss:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
          <ss:user name="user1" password="work4proj" authorities="ROLE_DEV" />
        </ss:user-service>
    </ss:authentication-provider>
  </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>
```

RAML code looks like.

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://localhost:9091/
title: booksAPI

securitySchemes:
 basic:
    type: Basic Authentication

/books:
  get:
   token: 
    type: string
    minLength: 10
    maxLength: 20
    required: true
    examples:
      {
        token: "1234abcd1234abcd"
      }
responses: 
  200:
    body:
```

But getting below error, when try to run in anypoint studio. There is no issue with raml file as it ran well in anypoint designer.

```
ERROR 2019-01-10 14:47:40,913 [main] 
org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ss:authentication-manager'.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.jav
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Add Below Namespaces

```
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

•    Add Below Schema

```
xsi:schemaLocation="  
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
```

•   Add Below lines in global declaration of the flow

```
<!-- Authentication security-->
<mule-ss:security-manager name="_muleSecurityManager" doc:name="Spring Security Provider">
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
<spring:beans>
   <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <ss:authentication-provider>
        <ss:user-service id="userService">
         <ss:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </ss:user-service>
      </ss:authentication-provider>
   </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>
```

•   Now apply security into the flow by adding the following line of code:

```
<mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="memory-provider"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly shows schema declaration issue.
The link that you followed clearly said to add following namespace.

```
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd"
```

**EDIT:**

I **don't find** `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd` in your namespace

So, Add

```
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
```

and in **xsi:schemaLocation**:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="  
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
```

Full example, Here is an example, Add your APIKit namespace as well:       :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd">

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="${http.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

  <!-- Authentication security-->
 <mule-ss:security-manager name="_muleSecurityManager" doc:name="Spring Security Provider">
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="userService">
                    <ss:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>
```

Comment: Hi Chowdhary, I have added all those namespaces. Still getting error